# Can't save retrieved from database drop down values in zend framework 2

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

First of all, excuse me for my poor english.

I have read a lot about populating a drop down with values from a database in zend framework 2, the 2 links that help me a lot are these:

1. http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html
2. http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/release-2.1.4/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html

This is what i did

1. I create a form, and add a field of type "categoryFieldset"

   class ProductForm extends Form
   {
       public function init()
       {
           // we want to ignore the name passed
           parent::__construct('product');
           $this->setName('product');
           $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
           $this->add(array(
               'name' => 'id',
               'type' => 'Hidden',
           ));
           $this->add(array(
               'name' => 'name',
               'type' => 'Text',
               'options' => array(
                   'label' => 'Name',
                ),
           ));
           $this->add(array(
               'name' => 'category',
               'type' => 'CategoryFieldSet',
           ));
           $this->add(array(
               'name' => 'submit',
               'type' => 'Submit',
               'attributes' => array(
                   'value' => 'Add',
                   'id' => 'submitbutton',
               ),
           ));
       }
   }
2. i create a class named categoryFieldset that extends from fieldset where I added a select field:

   class CategoryFieldset extends Fieldset
   {
       function _*construct(CategoryTable $categoryTable)
       {
           parent::*_construct('category_fieldset');

   ```
       $this->setHydrator(new ClassMethodsHydrator(false))->setObject(new Category());

       $categorySelectOptionsArray = $categoryTable->populateSelectCategory();
       $this->add(array(
               'name' => 'categoryField',
               'type' => 'Select',
               'options' => array(
                       'label' => 'Category',
                       'value_options' => $categorySelectOptionsArray,
               ),
       ));
   }
   ```

   }
3. Add code to my module file:

   public function getFormElementConfig()
   {
       return array(
           'factories' => array(
               'CategoryFieldSet' => function($sm) {
                   $serviceLocator = $sm->getServiceLocator();
                   $categoryTable = $serviceLocator->get('Administrador\Model\CategoryTable');
                   $fieldset = new CategoryFieldset($categoryTable);
                   return $fieldset;
               },
           )
       );
   }
4. My view has this:

   $form = $this->form;
   $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('product', array('action' => 'add')));
   $form->prepare();
   echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
   echo $this->formHidden($form->get('id'));
   echo $this->formRow($form->get('name'));
   echo "
   ";
   $category_fieldset = $form->get('category');
   echo $this->formRow($category_fieldset->get('categoryField'));
   echo "
   ";
   echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
   echo "
   ";
   echo $this->form()->closeTag();

Right now everything is fine, the select elements are showing the values from database, but my problem is when i try to add the data to the database, the field where is the dropdown of categories is saved with the value "0" instead of the id value of the category. I think the problem is the way the view is rendering the select field, when i checked the HTML code i notice that the name of the select field is "category[categoryField]" and it should be "category".

This is the HTML code:

```
<span>Category</span>
<select name="category[categoryField]">
<option value="1">Category 1</option>
<option value="2">Category 2</option>
<option value="3">Category 3</option>
<option value="4">Category 4</option>
<option value="5">Category 5</option>
</select>
```

I printed the $request->getPost() array in the viw and this is what it shows:

```
Zend\Stdlib\Parameters Object ( [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array ( [id] => [name] => Product1 [category] => Array ( [categoryField] => 2 ) [submit] => Add ) )
```

What do i need to do to make the field name shows like "category" or to be able to save that record to the database?

Comment: Do i understand you correctly, that your only problem is that your `Select` has the attribute `name="category[categoryField]"` instead of `name="category"`? In that case this is intended, since it appears you have added your `Element\Select` inside a `Zend\Form\Fieldset`. If this `Fieldset` is the only one, you may look for the attribute `use_as_base_fieldset` on the fieldset ;)

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your reply. Well, yes, my problem was i wanted the field name has the name 'category' instead 'category[categoryField]' in my add Form of my CRUD app. I already resolved the problem commenting the $form->prepare. But right now im having another problem in my update form, I have a Form, with 1 fieldset as base fieldset, inside have several fields and 4 fieldsets that inside has selects elements populated from a database, my problem is the $form->bind doesnt populate the selects fields inside my fieldset (inside my base fieldset), only populate the fields inside base fieldset.